# Ember.js: Preventing a href bubbling possible?

Tags: ember.js

I have a template where I have the following code:

```
<div {{bind-attr class=":suggestions isRecept::disabled"}} {{action "toggleRecept"}}>
    <!-- skipped the rest -->
    <a {{bind-attr href="recept_pdf" bubbles=false}}>Click for the recept!</a></p>      
</div>
```

I want to link to an external pdf file. However when a user click on the link, the toggleRecept visibility action is fired. The `bubbles=false` is incorrect code, but that is what I wanted.

I know it is possible to limit the action, but I am curious if it is possible to do some bubble preventing on a simple HTML attribute.

Comment: Do you have to put your `a` inside your `div`? Can you make your toggle button a separate element?

Comment: @claptimes thanks! That was the first solution I thought about, but I was thinking of an Ember way to handle this.... :)

Comment: The problem is  your binding your `click` action to the div which contains an `a`. I don't see how you could just isolate the `a` inside.

Comment: At the moment I have quick and dirty fixed this one. An extra div isolate the action part from the link part.